# Amplify a signal having a DC component without using an opamp

Tags: transistors, amplifier, synthesizer

I am building a simple modular synthesizer. I would like to keep everything simple and prefer to use discrete components over integrated circuits. My goal is to improve my knowledge about electronics.

How can I amplify a signal which has a DC component (e.g. 1V DC + a sine wave which is 1V peak to peak) without using an opamp?

It is easy to amplify a pure AC signal with a transistor, some resistors, and 2 capacitors (to decouple DC at input and output). However, now I want to also amplify the DC component, so the decoupling with the capacitors is not possible.

I am looking for a solution that doesn't have DC drift with temperature change, but it doesn't need to be perfectly linear.

Comment: What signal in a synth has a DC offset? Is it possible that you could just add the DC later on? Amplifying down to DC is a pain.

Comment: Depending on specs I think you might end up having to build an op-amp out of discrete components, with a matched pair of transistors for the input diff pair.  Or at least some sort of feedback amplifier topology.  Anything else and you will experience temperature drift, and you will have trouble with amplifying the DC component.  But maybe an X-Y problem?

Comment: @loudnoises: Most control voltages have dc offset. E.g. an envelope generator would generate the control voltage for a voltage controlled amplifier or voltage controlled filter. In most modular synthesizers, control voltage is also used for pitch control (e.g. one octave per volt).

Comment: Is this modular synthesizer thing meant to produce audio signals?  If so, it makes no sense to amplify DC.  DC, being below 20 Hz, is meaningless in audio.  It makes things much more difficult, and makes no sense, to have audio signal paths go all the way down to 0 frequency.

Comment: @OlinLathrop -- modular synths *do* have DC signals roaming around to *control* the various blocks....(VCAs/VCOs/VCFs)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't buy into your excuses for not using an opamp.

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using an op-amp? If you're setting yourself a challenge, then OK. If you believe there is some benefits to the sound, that isn't true though - it's a lie spread by the "old stuff is always better" club. There certainly are ways that non-linearity can sound good, but you're a long away from having the experience to recognise and characterise that non-linearity. And if you have good enough ears to hear it clearly in the first place - some people don't.

Comment: @Graham: thanks for your comment. I am well aware that it would be easier to use an Opamp (at least for the control signals which have DC). And I don't believe that everything old was better. For me, this project is a personal challenge.

Comment: @captain_error Cool - good luck with it. Sorry to jump to assumptions, but I've done a bit with hobbyist electronics, especially around audio and music, and there are mad levels of "urban legend engineering" in some of those groups!

Comment: @Graham: yes. People are discussing how certain cables "sound". Or they love the "sound" of tube amplifiers which are optimised so they have pretty much 0 harmonic distortion....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To keep the drift relatively low (it will be inferior to a monolithic op-amp because of the poor matching and thermal coupling) you can use a differential pair and use feedback like an op-amp.

Here is an example of a unity-gain stable amplifier made with discrete parts, from [this](https://sound-au.com/project07.htm) website.

[image]

C1 provides frequency compensation- and can be changed for stability. Q1 and Q2 should be thermally coupled for minimum drift (eg. put thermal compound between the two, face to face, and shrink wrap around them).

Output is class A so no crossover distortion, but drive capability is limited. Bias is power supply voltage dependent, so PSRR is poor. You can play with this in LTspice or on the bench.

Performance won't come close, in most respects, to a [modern monolithic amplifier designed for audio applications](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa1688.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What would be the disadvantages of just using the two input transistors Q1 and Q2 as a "long tailed pair" as described here: https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-12 (adding an extra 2k7 resistor for symmetry)? Without the rest of the circuit, I mean.

Comment: The rest of the circuit adds gain and frequency compensation so you can use negative feedback to get relatively linear behavior (and it yields more output voltage range).

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use just a transistor maintained in its linear region as an amplifier, but your goals to "keep everything simple" and "use discrete components" might be at odds, as you will quickly discover the difficulty of keeping the transistor in that region. @Spehro has been around a long time and knows of what he speaks.

Answer (score 1):

I spent 43 years in Broadcast Engineering.  A few more servicing large industrial motors and controllers.  Built several TV Stations and worked on AM FM and Directional Antenna Arrays.  Performed my share of component level troubleshooting.  Trained on Vacuum Tubes in radios and TV's and have worked on Transistor and IC Circuits.  I worked with Discrete components, they work best if properly laid out on a PC board.  Point-to-point would not be my preference.

There is a reason people use Integrated Circuits.  Discrete components, NPN, PNP transistors and some FETs had peculiarities that require temperature compensation to prevent avalanche or neutralization at some Audio and RF Frequencies. A gain-setting in NPN or PNP is usually set by the Emitter-Base Junction bias. Some components did not take well to point to point wiring, stray capacitance and coupling problems could be an issue.  Point to Point was popular among imported goods in the 60's. Not all discrete components are of the same grade or quality.   Of Course, like everything,*you get what you pay for*.

Discrete circuits seldom had just the simple parts count like your example Wiki-circuit.  The values of resistors are not exact and there may be compensation and offset settings required when working with discrete components which make a TO-5, DIP or a SIP a great investment.  Temperature compensation and transient protection are designed into the IC package. The circuit of Chapter 12 Wiki does not show those details.  Resistors are not of the more precise value of those internal to the IC.

What you gain from a die manufactured product is; **repeatable reliability and quick cost-effective replacement**.   Best to buy the products of reputable manufacturers from well-stocked suppliers.  Mouser, DigiKey, Newark come to mind, I am sure I have left out someone, perhaps Allied.  There are others, and regrettably, I don't design much anymore.

Just a suggestion, You might look-up Digikey; they have people on staff who can help you if you are truly bent on design using Discrete components.

I applaud your efforts and wish you the Best in your attempts to learn and grow!